# Animate text behind box

Tags: css, animation

I have a popup box that starts at page load, and I also have a fade in text animation on page load. The text fades infront of the popup box and then disappears behind it after it's duration. How can I cause the text animation to stay behind always?

Text fade in keyframes:

```
@keyframes scale { 0% { transform: scale(0.8); opacity: 0; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was add this: `z-index: 1; position:relative;` to the css of the pop up. The animated text then stayed behind.